# Fabric.js resizable rectangle with a label that has constant size

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I am trying to have some boxes (fabric.js rectangles) that highlight certain things on a background image.
These boxes should have a label that displays various information ( e.g. box height and width) as showed here:(https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGvDD.png)

but not resize whenever the boxes are resized.

Right now my implementation is as follows:

```
for (const box of boxCollection) {
        let rect = new fabric.Rect({
            left: box.c_x,
            top: box.c_y,
            angle: box.angle,
            width: box.w,
            height: box.h,
            originX: 'center',
            originY: 'center',
            cornerColor: 'green',
            fill: '',
            stroke: 'red',
            strokeWidth: 1,
            //  objectCaching: true,
            noScaleCache: false,
            strokeUniform: true,
        });

        var text = new fabric.Text(rect.width.toFixed(2) + ' x '+ rect.height.toFixed(2), {
            left: box.c_x,
            top: box.c_y + box.h / 2 + 5,
            fontSize: 10,
            originX: 'center',
            originY: 'center',

        });
        var group = new fabric.Group([rect, text]);
```

which just groups the two and creates a single object, hence the modification of size is applied to both.

Is there any way of keeping the two separated (as in not a group), having independent sizes, but have the label still under the box even if the box position is changed?